# Need to make my algorithm faster

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, math

I need to make my program faster, but I just can't figure out how. Here is the problem. I have a sequence of numbers sorted like this:

```
7
4 8
2 5 9
1 3 6 10

 7
  \
 4 8
  \ \
 2 5 9
  \ \ \
 1 3 6 10
```

I have to output a number depending on the input. The input is going to be two integers, think of them as x and y coordinates. The *x* is how many away from the left I go and the y is how many from the bottom I go. So say *x* and *y* are 1 and 1, then I would have to output 5.

```
 7

 4 8

 2-5 9
   |
 1 3 6 10
```

Now my code works and gets the correct number, but it is too slow.

```
def answer(x, y):
    last_num = 1
    arr_hold = [[1]]
    for i in range(2, x+(y+2)):
        reg_hold = []
        for j in range(last_num + 1, i + last_num + 1):
            if j == (i + last_num + 1) - 1:
                last_num = j
            if i == (x+(y+2)) - 1:
                reg_hold.append(j)
    print reg_hold
    return reg_hold[x]
```

Is there anything I can do to speed it up?
The max *x* or *y* can be is 100000 and the lowest is 0

Comment: @UrielEli What do you mean? I told you that x is how many times to move to the right and y is how many times to move upward.

Comment: Analyze the pattern. There's clearly a relationship between a number and its coordinates. If you can figure out what it is, there is no need to do looping.

Comment: If your code works without errors, a better place to ask could be [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a closed-form solution to this problem. The numbers along the bottom row are the triangular numbers. You can compute them with `n*(n+1)//2`. You can get your result by computing the right `n` and offsetting from the triangular number that it produces:

```
def answer(x, y):
    n = x + y + 1
    return n*(n+1)//2 - y
```

Comment: ah I was under the impression that this was supposed to work for any list of arrays :-)

Answer (score -1):

Store input as list of lists. Reverse the list of lists you just read. Then indexing is simple.

```
m = [[7], [4, 8], [2, 5, 9], [1, 3, 6, 10]] 
m = m[::-1] # reverse m = [[1, 3, 6, 10], [2, 5, 9], [4, 8], [7]] 
x = 1 
y = 1 
print m[x-1][y-1]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store a list like: [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]?